# MySQL optimization tips specific to a completely static database?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, myisam

I have a database that is about 20 GB in size. I want to know if there are any optimization tips specific to working with a database that is static.  When I mean static, I don't mean changes infrequently, I mean won't change at all.  Are there any extreme settings for values or other things that normally you stay away from with a volatile database, that can benefit a truly static database; especially considering there will only be SELECT statements and absolutely no INSERT statements?  I'm using MyISAM tables.

-- roschler

Comment: What are you indexing by? What are you storing?

Comment: @Nick ODell - inventory items.  Look-ups are on the usual things, title, manufacturer, etc.

Comment: Is this a lookup (i.e. an exact match is required) or a search (i.e. if I search for "hat" it should find all products with "hat" in the title)? Second, are you sure this isn't premature optimization?

Comment: @Nick ODell - there are some FULLTEXT searches involved.  Not sure what you mean by "premature optimization".

Comment: You need to give us the database schema if you want to have that question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything is MyISAM, you need to focus on two major things:

**KEY CACHE**

The main mechanism used for caching is the key cache. It only caches index pages from .MYI files. To size your key cache, run the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(KBS/POWER(1024,IF(PowerOfTwo<0,0,IF(PowerOfTwo>3,0,PowerOfTwo)))+0.4999),
SUBSTR(' KMG',IF(PowerOfTwo<0,0,IF(PowerOfTwo>3,0,PowerOfTwo))+1,1)) recommended_key_buffer_size
FROM (SELECT LEAST(POWER(2,32),KBS1) KBS FROM
(SELECT SUM(index_length) KBS1 FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')) AA) A,
(SELECT 2 PowerOfTwo) B;
```

This will give the Recommended Setting for MyISAM Key Cache (key_buffer_size) given your current data set ([the query will cap the recommendation at 4G (4096M)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size)).For 32-bit OS, 4GB is the limit. For 64-bit, 8GB.

**FULLTEXT Indexes**

You should change the stopword list. You may want to change the stop words because MySQL will not index [this list of 643 words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). Try creating your own stopword list and changing the min word length.

Step 1) Create a stop word list of your own. You could add 'a','an', and 'the'.

```
echo "a" > /var/lib/mysql/custom_stopwords.txt<BR>
echo "an" >> /var/lib/mysql/custom_stopwords.txt<BR>
echo "the" >> /var/lib/mysql/custom_stopwords.txt
```

Step 2) Add these options to /etc/my.cnf

```
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file=/var/lib/mysql/custom_stopwords.txt
```

Step 3) service mysql restart

Step 4) Create new FULLTEXT indexes. Any existing FULLTEXT indexes before restart of mysql should be reindexed.

Give These Ideas a Try !!!